# Oracle JDK Usage Logging

Tags: java

JDK 13 Release Notes include *Differences Between Oracle JDK and Oracle's OpenJDK*

It states that:

> Usage Logging is only available in Oracle JDK

What's Usage Logging and why is it available only in Oracle JDK?

Is it related to [Java Usage Tracker](https://docs.oracle.com/javacomponents/advanced-management-console-2/user-guide/java-usage.htm#JSAMV127)?

> Java Usage Tracker is a feature of the JRE. When enabled on a computer, Java Usage Tracker (JUT) tracks the use of applications and JREs on that computer. Advanced Management Console collects the information from the Usage Tracker and presents it in reports

Because it's refer to also in [OpenJDK](https://bugs.openjdk.java.net/browse/JDK-8037918)

> JDK-8037918
> System-wide configuration for Java Usage Tracker Status:RESOLVED

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This refers to the [Java Usage Tracker](https://docs.oracle.com/javacomponents/usage-tracker/overview/toc.htm#JSUTO-GUID-6642AAD5-85A1-462F-9D77-09A52DF72404).

> Java Usage Tracker tracks how Java Runtime Environments (JREs) are being used in your systems. The output of Java Usage Tracker is a plain text, comma-separated record that contains the JRE version, the application being run, and other details. This record is appended to a file or sent over the network in a User Datagram Protocol (UDP) packet.

Apparently, the recommended tool for capturing (?) and analyzing the usage information is the Advanced Management Console.  That is an Oracle proprietary tool that is not part of OpenJDK, but is available to people with a Java Oracle subscription.

For more information:

- [Advanced Management Console User's Guide - 4 Java Usage](https://docs.oracle.com/javacomponents/advanced-management-console-2/user-guide/java-usage.htm)
- https://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javaseproducts/advanced-mgmt/advancedmanagementconsole-2254207.html

---

> Why is it available only in Oracle JDK?

It is an Oracle business decision.

---

> It is referred to by OpenJDK Bug [JDK-8037918](https://bugs.openjdk.java.net/browse/JDK-8037918)

That is the original request for the implementation of the feature.  Note that JDK-8037918 doesn't give a version of the OpenJDK codebase in which the feature was implemented ... which is normal practice for resolved issues.

I have copies of various OpenJDK source trees on my home machine (for research purposes).  In the OpenJDK 11 tree for example, there are references to "usagetracker" in some build files, but no trace (that I could find) of any related implementation in the source code tree.

Answer (score 1):

***Disclaimer:** I work for Oracle at the Java Platform Group but my answers in stack overflow are my own, not official Oracle answers.*

[Java usage tracking](http://%20https://docs.oracle.com/javacomponents/usage-tracker/overview/) is a feature available in Oracle JDK, but not (yet) in OpenJDK.

Oracle has done some work to move the code to OpenJDK but this is not complete yet. The current implementation uses internal APIs and Oracle-branded APIs which need to be converted to OpenJDK alternatives before it can be migrated. As part of the migration work the feature is being rebranded to "usage logging" which is a more accurate description of what it does.  That is why  jira entries sometimes refer to "usage logging" and other times to "usage tracking".

Advanced Management Console is a solution that relies on the usage logging/tracking functionality to create an maintain and inventory of Java Runtimes and applications using them.